# Spring/Mongo, query with $geoIntersects always return null

Tags: java, mongodb

I have this class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "zones")
public class Zone {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private Map<DayOfWeek, Integer> ridesPerDay;

    private GeoJsonPolygon area;
```

An example on how the Zone document appears:

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("655cc665c85d816e72f86e68"),
    "area" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [
            [
                [
                    12.3893227,
                    41.11640959999997
                ],
                [
                    12.489322699999999,
                    41.11640959999997
                ],
                [
                    12.489322699999999,
                    41.21640959999997
                ],
                [
                    12.3893227,
                    41.21640959999997
                ]
            ]
        ]
    },
```

I also have another class, called CitizenRequest, which is:

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "citizenRequest")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class CitizenRequest {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private Date creationDate;

    private PointPath starterPoint;
}
```

Now, this *PointPath* variable has longitude and latitude in it.

What i want to do is to cycle through a list of CitizenRequests, and find in which zone does the citizenRequests coordinates fall.

To do so, i want to use $geoIntersects, which apparently is what i need.

So, what i do in my code is:

- Finding the minimum and maximum longitude and latitude
- Use them to create zones
- Cycle through the requests, and find in which zone they fall

This is my implementation:

```
@Override
    public void generateZonesFromLatLong() {

        AggregationResults<Map<String, Double>> result = citizenRequestController.getMinMaxCoordinates();

        System.out.println(result.getMappedResults());

        if (!result.getMappedResults().isEmpty()) {
            Map<String, Double> resultMap = result.getMappedResults().get(0);

            Double leftLongitude = resultMap.get("leftLongitude");
            Double rightLongitude = resultMap.get("rightLongitude");
            Double topLatitude = resultMap.get("topLatitude");
            Double bottomLatitude = resultMap.get("bottomLatitude");


            // START GENERATING ZONES
            int totSqr = 0;

            System.out.println("Starting from lon: " + leftLongitude + " to lon: " + rightLongitude);
            System.out.println("Starting from lat: " + topLatitude + " to lat: " + bottomLatitude);

            // clear the collection (i need to do this for work reasons)

            zoneRepository.deleteAll();

            for (double lon = leftLongitude; lon < rightLongitude; lon += incr) {
                for (double lat = topLatitude; lat > bottomLatitude; lat -= incr) {

                    Zone zone = new Zone();

                    zone.setSquareCoordinates(lon, lon + incr, lat, lat - incr);

                    zoneRepository.save(zone);

                    totSqr++;

                    }
                }

            System.out.println("Saved " + totSqr + " zones.");
            }   else {
            System.out.println("No result found.");
        }




               

                // STARTING REQUESTS ANALYSIS

                List<CitizenRequest> citizenRequestList = citizenRequestController.getAllCitizenRequests();

                for (CitizenRequest request : citizenRequestList){
                    
                    // converting coordinates into geojsonpoint

                    Double requestLongitude = request.getStarterPoint().getLongitude();
                    Double requestLatitude = request.getStarterPoint().getLatitude();

                    GeoJsonPoint reqCoordGeoJson = new GeoJsonPoint(requestLongitude, requestLatitude);


                   Zone resultZone = zoneRepository.findZoneContainingPoint(reqCoordGeoJson);

                    System.out.println("The zone is: " + resultZone);

                    }
                }
            }


// Just for the sake of understanding, this is what the setSquareCoordinates method does:

public void setSquareCoordinates(double leftLon, double rightLon,double topLat, double bottomLat ) {
        GeoJsonPoint bottomLeft = new GeoJsonPoint(leftLon, bottomLat);
        GeoJsonPoint bottomRight = new GeoJsonPoint(rightLon, bottomLat);
        GeoJsonPoint topRight = new GeoJsonPoint(rightLon, topLat);
        GeoJsonPoint topLeft = new GeoJsonPoint(leftLon, topLat);

        GeoJsonPolygon area = new GeoJsonPolygon(bottomLeft, bottomRight, topRight, topLeft);

        this.area = area;
    }
```

Also, these are my two repositories:

CitizenRequestRepo:

```
@Repository
public interface CitizenRequestRepository extends MongoRepository<CitizenRequest, String> {


    @Aggregation(pipeline = {
            "{$group: { _id: null, " +
                    "leftLongitude: { $min: '$starterPoint.longitude' }, " +
                    "rightLongitude: { $max: '$starterPoint.longitude' }, " +
                    "topLatitude: { $max: '$starterPoint.latitude' }, " +
                    "bottomLatitude: { $min: '$starterPoint.latitude' }" +
                    "}}"
    })
    public AggregationResults<Map<String, Double>> getMinMaxCoordinates();
```

ZoneRepo:

```
 @Query("{ 'area': { $geoIntersects: { $geometry: ?0 } } }")
    Zone findZoneContainingPoint(GeoJsonPoint point);
```

My problem is that this last method always returns null.

I have no problem with the 'creating zones' part, since as you can see, i posted an example of my JSON and it works like a charm.

I don't know what the problem is. Anyone can help?

Comment: First of all, are you sure your polygon is closed? From [official doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/geojson/#polygons-with-a-single-ring), *first and last coordinates must match in order to close the polygon*. Can you try again with the polygon closed?